# How to gain permission in HealthKit for writing workout route using Cordova

Tags: cordova, permissions, telerik, healthkit

How can I ask user permission for WorkoutRoute in a CordovaApp on iphone?

Meaning writing workout location into HealthKit via `HKWorkoutRouteBuilder.insertRouteData`, this is done by a native WatchKit App.

I tried (by using the telerik.plugin.healthkit)

```
var supportedTypes = [
  'HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned',
  'HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate',
  'HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDistanceWalkingRunning',
  'HKWorkoutRouteTypeIdentifier',
  'HKWorkoutTypeIdentifier'
];

window.plugins.healthkit.requestAuthorization(...
```

but so far no chance to get: Workout Routes (marked brown in image) - this is from Speedysloth example:

[image: Healthkit Permissions given to SpeedySloth App]

Comment: Please mention which plugin you are using for healthkit. are creating your own ?

Comment: I am using the 'com.telerik.plugins.healthkit' from GitHub (no I am a beginner and not creating my own).

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed requesting access to 'Workout Routes' by extending the plugin (telerik.plugin.health) in file: Healthkit.m / function getHKSampleType() I added:

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        type = [HKObjectType seriesTypeForIdentifier:elem];
        if (type != nil) {
            return type;
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
}
```

since seriesType is new starting with iOS 11.